# How to change global settings for project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, javafx-2

Ok people.

First, I hope you won't downvote this question, and this is the deal.

I need to start working on a JavaFX application as a part of my contract, and a IDE of my choice is IntelliJ IDEA. The only reason for choosing this IDE is because I used PyCharm and RubyMine before, so it seemed like a good choice.

I'm not a JavaFX expert either, but I just wanted to prepare myself a little, since the last time I worked with Java was version 6.

I usually work with plain old text-editors (since most of my work is Ruby and C++), so my knowledge of configuring any kind of IDE is fairly limited.

And this is my problem.

Every time I try to create a new JavaFX application 
I get this dialog.

[image: start]

As you can see no additional options for this kind of Application, but straightforward creation.

The generated output results in this:

[image: generated project]

I tried looking into the official documentation, and the only thing I found about the project configuration was [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/developing-a-javafx-hello-world-application-coding-examples.html).

I honestly find it really tedious to adjust the sample package, and edit files every time I want to create a new project.

Is there a way of global configuration that would allow me to start with an empty JavaFX application without a sample directory, and how?

Or if someone has a better idea IDE/editor-wise it'd be also very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind the question.

I found a solution, so here it is if someone needs it for the future reference.

1. Create a default project, and edit it according to your own needs (I deleted a whole sample package, and replaced with my own personal one)
2. In **.idea** folder edit **workspace.xml** file, and remove/replace all the **sample/Main.java** references, and insert your own ones according to your project package and Java files in it
3. **Tools -> Save as project template**

And that's it.

Next time you run IDEA you'll be presented with User defined projects where you can run your template from.